# How can I fill the remaining blank portion of the page in Itext5?

Tags: java, itext

[image]

As seen above，i used pdfTable as the body part of the page. Now i want to fill the entire body with the border,column,row of the table, if the table does not fill the entire body part.As shown in the picture below.

[image]

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm afraid this is non-trivial - there is no information in the PDF that its content is generated from some iText `PdfPTable` object, let alone which settings were used in that object. Consequentially there is no top-level mechanism in iText for continuing such a table. Of course you may analyze the content of the existing PDF (a heap of text chunks and lines) and try and deduce an appropriately initialized `PdfPTable` object to continue the existing table but that is a lot of work.

Comment: Ok，I  know that this kind of demand is not necessary,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *sort of* cheat to accomplish this if you do it while you are creating the table.

I'll offer a partial solution that takes advantage of one of the complexities tables in PDFs: Tables are just lines in PDFs. They aren't structured content.

You can take advantage of this though- keep track of where you are are drawing vertical lines while rendering the table and simply continue them to the bottom of the page.

Let's create a new cell event. It keeps track of 4 things: `left` which is the far left x coordinate of the table, `right` which is the far right x coordinate of the table, `xCoordinates` which is a set of all the x coordinates we draw vertical lines, and finally `cellHeights` which is a list off all the cell heights.

```
class CellMarginEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

    Set<Float> xCoordinates = new HashSet<Float>();
    Set<Float> cellHeights = new HashSet<Float>();

    Float left = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Float right = Float.MIN_VALUE;

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell pdfPCell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] pdfContentBytes) {
        this.xCoordinates.add(rectangle.getLeft());
        this.xCoordinates.add(rectangle.getRight());

        this.cellHeights.add(rectangle.getHeight());

        left = Math.min(left,rectangle.getLeft());
        right = Math.max(right, rectangle.getRight());

    }


    public Set<Float> getxCoordinates() {
        return xCoordinates;
    }

}
```

We'll then add all of our cells to the table, but *not* add the table to the document just yet

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

    CellMarginEvent cellMarginEvent = new CellMarginEvent();
    for (int aw = 0; aw < 320; aw++) {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Cell: " + aw));
        cell.setCellEvent(cellMarginEvent);
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
```

No we add get top- the top position of our table, and add the table to the document.

```
float top = writer.getVerticalPosition(false);
document.add(table);
```

Then we draw the vertical and horizontal lines of the completed table. For the height of each cell I just used the first element in `cellHeights`.

```
Set<Float> xCoordinates = cellMarginEvent.getxCoordinates();

    //Draw the column lines
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    for (Float x : xCoordinates) {
        canvas.moveTo(x, top);
        canvas.lineTo(x, 0 + document.bottomMargin());

        canvas.closePathStroke();
    }
    Set<Float> cellHeights = cellMarginEvent.cellHeights;
    Float cellHeight = (Float)cellHeights.toArray()[0];
    float currentPosition = writer.getVerticalPosition(false);
    //Draw the row lines
    while (currentPosition >= document.bottomMargin()) {
        canvas.moveTo(cellMarginEvent.left,currentPosition);
        canvas.lineTo(cellMarginEvent.right,currentPosition);
        canvas.closePathStroke();
        currentPosition -= cellHeight;
    }
```

And finally close the document:

```
document.close()
```

Example output:

[image]

Note that the only reason I say this is an incomplete examples is because there may be some adjustments you need to make to `top` in the case of header cells, or there may be custom cell styling (background color, line color, etc) you need to account for yourself.

I'll also note another downfall that I just thought of- in the case of tagged PDFs this solution fails to add tagged table cells, and thus would break compliance if you have that requirement.

Comment: Thanks you,the solution you provided is feasible for me.I wang to share you comment share to my Twitter. Very thankful!